# the event firing with track.stop() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

i want to stop sharing my video call and i use the `peerConnection.removeStream(localStream);` function with the event  `onremovestream` but i find that it's deprecated and then the `onremovestream` doesn't fired anymore,i tried  to use the `track.stop()` function like this :

```
 var videoTracks = localStream.getVideoTracks();
    videoTracks.forEach(function(track) {
    track.stop();
    });
```

now i want to know the event fired with that function to know when the video call is stopped in the remote peer .
any help ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var videoTracks = stream.getTracks();
videoTracks.forEach(track => track.stop());
```

Notice that if you use `.stop()`the stream is finally ended and you can't launch it again.

Comment: okey i'll do but how can i know that the call is stopped in the other peer ?is there an even fired with this function?

Comment: yes i understand .when i use this function the video process will be stopped everywhere thanks a lot for your help Mr , i have just need to change my design and display a message telling the second users that the call is stopped by the other.

Comment: track.stop() will end the track and stop capture from a camera (or other source), and is normally what you use with webrtc/getUserMedia.